# Create an interactive map leaflet-ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, leaflet, openstreetmap

In order to create an interactive map consisting of several layers I use the  plugin leaflet-ajax with downloading of the files. geojson. When you direct at the object of the layer, the attribute information (object`s attributes) displays.
It is required to include a link to the html page in a number of the object`s attributes. I rack my brains over this task a week, please, help me know how to do it!
The code is given below.

```
   {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
        }
    },

    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": 2,
            "date": "2012\/02\/05",
            "material": "plastic",
            "Number": 1,
            "support,feeder": "2 2"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPoint",
            "coordinates": [
                [34.377387101428354, 54.063054027736584]
            ]
        }
    }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": 4,
            "date": "2012\/02\/05",
            "material": "plastic",
            "Number": 1,
            "support , feeder": "4 2"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "MultiPoint",
            "coordinates": [
                [34.378052287959541, 54.062481025595972]
            ]
        }
    }, ]
}
```

Comment: Define what you mean by "interactive". Leaflet allows you out-of-the-box to create popups (when hovering or clicking an area or marker) or to bind a (javascript) function to an event.

Comment: http://213.137.240.143:7778/rcs_8/index1.html when the mouse cursor and clicking on a marker

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is happening because you are never actually adding the layers to the map. Make sure to add `map.addLayer(dorogi)` for each one of those AJAX layers after you initialize them.

Or you can watch the `data:loaded` event and add them after all data has been downloaded. Docs at https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax